# how to make the RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT message stick there?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that makes use of the `SpeechRecognizer` and `RecognizerIntent` in Android.

The way this app is supposed to work is: the user is shown some text on the screen, and the user has to read that string/text aloud into the phone's mic (that's how the `SpeechRecognizer` is used.) The speech recognition works flawlessly! My problem is with the prompt message sent though the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
```

This prompt message is shown in google's speech recognizer `dialog box` when it pops open.

**Problem:** As soon as the user starts speaking, the above `prompt` message disappears and gets replaced by the user's own words (what the user speaks into the mic) as being recorded. But since the text
**(initial prompt message)** has disappeared, the user doesn't know what to read/speak anymore!

The idea behind this is that I want the user to be able to read the text on the screen, and speak (what he's reading), into the mic at the same time.

Is there any way to make the prompt message inside the dialog box **not disappear** when the speech recognition starts?

Here's the simple code:

```
public void startSpeechRecognizer(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST);
}
```

I've gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything on this. Is there any way to achieve this, or any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot and have come to realize that the default SpeechRecognizer dialog box (the one that pops up when it starts recording), cannot be given any special UI attributes.

To achieve a different UI, one would have to make a custom dialog box by defining a custom view, possibly extend the same SpeechRecognizer class to have features like displaying text or images in the speech recording pop up.

As a result, I'm closing this question.